# jQuery circle progress bar and percentage text animation when screen visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, screen, offset

I'm a novice in jQuery and I'm using jquery-circle-progress plugin by kottenator. I've four circles and I want to animate its bar and percentage text when it's area visible on the screen. Like most of websites make the effect.

Could anyone please help me to make that effect with a little explanation? Thanks in advance, Dear. [My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/minhaz/9jfn6mh9/3/)

HTML:

```
<section class="firstDiv"></section>
<section class="secondDiv"></section>
<div class="thirdDiv">
  <div id="circle1">
    <span class="rate">85%</span>
  </div>
    <div id="circle2">
    <span class="rate">90%</span>
  </div>
    <div id="circle3">
    <span class="rate">80%</span>
  </div>
    <div id="circle4">
    <span class="rate">70%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
section{ height: 700px; overflow: hidden;}
.firstDiv{ background: blue;}
.secondDiv{ background: yellow;}
.thirdDiv div{
         float: left;
         width: 25%;
         overflow: hidden;
         margin: 50px 0;
         position: relative;
         }
.rate{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 25%;
}
```

JS:

```
  $('#circle1').circleProgress({
    value: 0.85,
    size: 100,
    fill: {
      gradient: [ "#FD0000" , "#FD7300", "#FDBD00"]
    }
  });


  $('#circle2').circleProgress({
    value: 0.90,
    size: 100,
    fill: {
      gradient: ["#00B050", "#00CA00", "#9EEC00"]
    }
  });


  $('#circle3').circleProgress({
    value: 0.80,
    size: 100,
    fill: {
      gradient: ["#FDFD00", "#FDE700", "#CDF500"]
    }
  });


  $('#circle4').circleProgress({
    value: 0.70,
    size: 100,
    fill: {
      gradient: ["#123FAA", "#3914AE", "#0B63A3"]
    }
  });
```

[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/minhaz/9jfn6mh9/3/)

Comment: Those circles appear to animate in that fiddle.  What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Those circles animate as DOM loaded, but I want to animate it when user will come on that DIV, then it will animate. thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, It was a pretty good experience. I've solved the problem by using jquery.appear plugin. I've insert my full code into this portion of code:

```
    var el = $('.circle'),
        inited = false;

    el.appear({ force_process: true });

    el.on('appear', function() {
      if (!inited) {
        el.circleProgress({ value: 0.7 });
        inited = true;
      }
    });
```

It's a nice plugin, which execute the code when the div(in my case .thirdDiv) on screen. My full JS code is below:

```
    var el = $('.thirdDiv'),
        inited = false;

    el.appear({ force_process: true });

    el.on('appear', function() {
      if (!inited) {
        $("#circle1").circleProgress({
        value: 0.7,
        size: 100,
        fill: {
          gradient: [ "#FD0000" , "#FD7300", "#FDBD00"]
            }
        });

        $("#circle2").circleProgress({
        value: 0.90,
        size: 100,
        fill: {
          gradient: ["#00B050", "#00CA00", "#9EEC00"]
        }
      });


      $("#circle3").circleProgress({
        value: 0.80,
        size: 100,
        fill: {
          gradient: ["#FDFD00", "#FDE700", "#CDF500"]
        }
      });

      $("#circle4").circleProgress({
        value: 0.70,
        size: 100,
        fill: {
          gradient: ["#123FAA", "#3914AE", "#0B63A3"]
        }
      }); 

        inited = true;
      }

});
```

Thanks everybody :)